# Calculating the equilibrium price. ( Theory- whith no smooth supply and demands curves)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, economics

I was looking for a theory wich explain the following problem:

I have the next , demand, supply curve:

[image]

The book didn't explain how to compute the equilibrium price with this market (only was named). I have no idea, how to compute the equilibrium price on this situation, and I try to search about the theory or model must be applied to solve it, but I can't find any like this example.

**I will apreciate if someone know where can I find the material to solve it. Thanks for your help.**

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does this book generally use "dollars" as the units of supply and demand? As far as I can recall, in all other sources I've read the units of the supply and demand functions are just a quantity of goods, and the dollar amount is gotten by multiplying supply or demand by price.

Comment: Does the book say that it is possible to compute an equilibrium price in cases like that? [Here are some economics materials](http://eclass.uoa.gr/modules/document/file.php/ECON258/Producer%20Theory%20Lectures/5.%20firm_market_bw.pdf) that say, "Discontinuity in supply functions may mean that there is no equilibrium." (See slide 10.)